# How is the socket.io directory recognised

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io

Online examples will usually include the socket.io library using

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

However, I was wondering why this works even though I don't have a socket.io folder in my directory. Does running `node index.js` automatically create this socket.io folder?

Comment: I’m confused. Do you have any code you’re struggling with? Or are you asking how to install/use the library?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm asking how this part of the code works, even when I didn't create a socket.io folder

Comment: You’ve left out all the parts where you explain how you made the project, how you run the code, and how you use the socket.io library. Did you install it using npm?

Comment: I did `npm init` to create the project. Then, I installed express and socket.io using npm. I run the code using `node index.js`

Comment: Since the library has been installed using npm there now exists a socket.io folder inside `node_modules`.

Comment: I can see that there a socket.io folder in `node_module`, but from my understanding, that folder and the folder being referenced in the code are different (source: https://socket.io/get-started/chat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The socket.io server listens for all incoming requests that start with `/socket.io` and "steals" those requests for itself, keeping them from the regular http server that the socket.io server is sharing.

When the socket.io server sees that this is a request for the `socket.io.js` file, the socket.io  server then reaches into its own `node_modules/socket.io/client-dist` directory to get the client-side `socket.io.js` file and sends it back to the client.

If you look at what you will find in `node_modules/socket.io/client-dist` directory, you will see the file `socket.io.js` sitting there.  That's the file that the socket.io server sends back to the client.  This is client-side code, only on the server for the purposes of being sent to the client when it asks for it.

Keep in mind that responses to incoming paths with a nodejs http server are not necessarily about file directories on the server at all.  If any code hooked up to the http server handles an incoming request, it can decide what it wants to send as the response, from anywhere in the server (whether from a file or not).  Only specific middleware tools like `express.static()` look on the server's hard disk for a directory that matches the incoming request.